# MySQL ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, data-migration, mezzanine

I am trying to move content from wordpress posts to mezzanine using:

```
INSERT INTO mezdb.blog_blogpost (id, user_id, publish_date,
          content, title, description, slug, updated, status) 
SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_author, post_date, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt,
    post_name, post_modified, post_status 
FROM wpdb.wp_posts  WHERE wp_posts.post_type IN ('story');
```

but I get

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`mezdb`.`blog_blogpost`, CONSTRAINT
>   `site_id_refs_id_ac21095f` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES
>   `django_site` (`id`))

mezdb schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_blogpost` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `comments_count` integer NOT NULL,
    `keywords_string` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    `rating_count` integer NOT NULL,
    `rating_sum` integer NOT NULL,
    `rating_average` double precision NOT NULL,
    `site_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    `slug` varchar(2000),
    `_meta_title` varchar(500),
    `description` longtext NOT NULL,
    `gen_description` bool NOT NULL,
    `created` datetime,
    `updated` datetime,
    `status` integer NOT NULL,
    `publish_date` datetime,
    `expiry_date` datetime,
    `short_url` varchar(200),
    `in_sitemap` bool NOT NULL,
    `content` longtext NOT NULL,
    `user_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `allow_comments` bool NOT NULL,
    `featured_image` varchar(255)
);
```

I'm noob in SQL so appreciate your hints.

Comment: i guess some rows are already inserted , then you need to update it not insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
INSERT INTO mezdb.blog_blogpost (id, user_id, publish_date,
      content, title, description, slug, updated, status) 
SELECT DISTINCT ID, post_author, post_date, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt,
post_name, post_modified, post_status 
FROM wpdb.wp_posts  WHERE wp_posts.post_type IN ('story');
set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

**Note:** this is an easy workaround, but definitely **not a good idea**. Or you should be very well aware of what you're doing.

The main point of [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) is to maintain [the referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity), in other words, *data consistency*. Simply said, the database doesn't allow you to insert wrong value to a column with the foreign key. Now it has to be clear that disabling the *foreign key check* to be able to insert a wrong value smells very fishy.

See StuartLC's answer for a proper solution.

Comment: But wait. What's the point of having a foreign key if you disable its checking? If anyone will use your query, he just created an inconsistency in his database. The main point of the foreign keys is to maintain the [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity), in other words, data consistency. It just doesn't make a sense to create a foreign key in a table to prevent inserting wrong values and then disable it to insert a wrong value.

Answer (score 4):

`site_id` is defined as `integer NOT NULL` and as per the error message, has a foreign key to `django_site (id)`.

You haven't specified `site_id` in your insert list. You will need to include a value for `site_id` and give it a value which exists in table `django_site`, column `id`.

Alternatively, if you are not able to determine a valid `site_id` value, change the `blog_blogpost` table column `site_id` to allow NULL (i.e. `site_id integer NULL`). Obviously `INNER JOINS between`blog_blogpost`and`django_site` will now need to be reconsidered.

Answer (score 2):

`django_site` table should contain at least one record, and each record in `blog_blogpost` must have a reference to it - `blog_blogpost.site_id` field is a reference to `django_site.id`, as error message says.

So, you just have to put a constant in your query:

```
INSERT INTO mezdb.blog_blogpost(
  id, 
  user_id, 
  publish_date, 
  content, 
  title, 
  description, 
  slug, 
  updated, 
  status, 
  site_id) -- This is a reference field
SELECT 
  DISTINCT id, 
  post_author, 
  post_date, 
  post_content, 
  post_title, 
  post_excerpt, 
  post_name, 
  post_modified, 
  post_status, 
  1 -- This is your constant, it may be different - look it up in 'django_site'
FROM wpdb.wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_type IN ('story');
```

Comment: Well, this one gives: ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mezdb`.`blog_blogpost`, CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_01a962b8` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`)). I tried other numbers than 1.not effect

Comment: @qliq That's a different error, but the problem is the same. Your `auth_user` table may be empty, so another constraint fails. You should migrate users first, preserving their IDs, and then it should be fine, unless other constraints will fail. The idea is: **migrate tables which have no constraints first, then migrate tables which reference these tables, when migrate tables which reference those "second order" tables and so on** - imagine you recreate a tree starting from "leafs".

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (mezdb.blog_blogpost, CONSTRAINT
>   site_id_refs_id_ac21095f FOREIGN KEY (site_id) REFERENCES django_site
>   (id))

**Table blog_blogpost Schema:**

> `The  site_id` integer NOT NULL

which means `site_id` is not NULL field and  from the error message we can come to the conclusion that it is referenced to the `django_site(id))` of the another table.

**Root Cause of the problem:**

1. in your insert query you didn't pass `siteid`
2. keep in mind that the `site_id` value your passing should be there in `django_site(id))` column as it is referenced as the foreign key

**Solution:**

1. Pass `Site_id` value which is present in `django_site(id))` column of the table referenced.